# hep with CTE in Postgresql - join tables

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

i have following query.

```
with sh as
(select payor, name_policy, program, count(distinct event_id) as sevents from cart_item_funder_policy_worker where event_Status like 'Show%' 
    and event_time between '2022-04-01' and '2022-09-30' group by payor, name_policy, program),
qty_s as
(select payor, name_policy, program, sum(item_qty) as qty_show from cart_item_funder_policy_worker where event_Status like 'Show%' 
    and event_time between '2022-04-01' and '2022-09-30' group by payor, name_policy, program),
ns as
(select payor, name_policy, program, count(distinct event_id) as nsevents from cart_item_funder_policy_worker where event_Status like 'No Show%' 
    and event_time between '2022-04-01' and '2022-09-30' group by payor, name_policy, program),
qty_ns as
(select payor, name_policy, program, sum(item_qty) as qty_no_show from cart_item_funder_policy_worker where event_Status like 'No Show%' 
    and event_time between '2022-04-01' and '2022-09-30' group by payor, name_policy, program)
    
select sh.payor, sh.name_policy, sh.program, sh.sevents, qty_s.qty_show, ns.nsevents, qty_ns.qty_no_show
from sh
full join ns on sh.name_policy = ns.name_policy
full join qty_s on qty_s.name_policy = sh.name_policy
full join qty_ns on qty_ns.name_policy = ns.name_policy;
```

as you can see that i only want to see the (count of `event_id` and sum of `item_qty`) grouped by `payor, name_policy, program`. but the above query groups the result by `sh.sevents, qty_s.qty_show, ns.nsevents, qty_ns.qty_no_show` as well.

can you please provide any assistance in figuring out how i can avoid grouping of `sh.sevents, qty_s.qty_show, ns.nsevents, qty_ns.qty_no_show` in my query.

Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE cart_item_funder_policy_worker
( payor          VARCHAR
, name_policy    VARCHAR
, program        VARCHAR
, item_qty       INTEGER
, event_id       INTEGER
, event_date     DATE
, event_status   VARCHAR
);
```

thanks

Comment: Did you find my answer helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're nearly there and you can simplify your CTEs to perform both the `COUNT` and `SUM` aggregates over the same data.

There doesn't appear to be a need for a `FULL JOIN` here. When will you have data in `sh` or `ns` that doesn't exist in `cart_item_funder_policy_worker`? `LEFT JOIN` will produce a row in the result set where you have data in `cart_item_funder_policy_worker` but not in `sh` or `ns`. Or just `INNER JOIN`/`JOIN` if you don't care about joining against `NULL`.

I didn't test it but I believe you can get the aggregates down to one block with something like this:

```
WITH data AS
(
    SELECT payor
         , name_policy
         , program
         , item_qty
         , event_id
         , event_status
      FROM cart_item_funder_policy_worker
     WHERE event_time BETWEEN '2022-04-01' AND '2022-09-30'
)
, aggs AS
(
    SELECT d.name_policy
         , COUNT(DISTINCT d.event_id) FILTER (WHERE d.event_status LIKE 'Show%') AS sevents
         , COUNT(DISTINCT d.event_id) FILTER (WHERE d.event_status LIKE 'No Show%') AS nsevents
         , SUM(d.item_qty) FILTER (WHERE d.event_status LIKE 'Show%') AS qty_show
         , SUM(d.item_qty) FILTER (WHERE d.event_status LIKE 'No Show%') AS qty_no_show
      FROM data d
     GROUP BY d.payor, d.name_policy, d.program
)
SELECT DISTINCT 
       d.payor
     , d.name_policy
     , d.program
     , a.sevents
     , a.qty_show
     , a.nsevents
     , a.qty_no_show
  FROM data d
  LEFT JOIN aggs a ON d.name_policy = a.name_policy
;
```

---

Or something like this:

`SELECT` all of the data you're going to be aggregating over in the first CTE, then calculate your aggregates in a separate CTE. In your aggregate portions, `SELECT` only your `JOIN` fields and the aggregates. Finally, grab your desired result set.

```
WITH data AS
(
    SELECT payor
         , name_policy
         , program
         , item_qty
         , event_id
         , event_status
      FROM cart_item_funder_policy_worker
     WHERE event_time BETWEEN '2022-04-01' AND '2022-09-30'
)
, sh AS
(
    SELECT d.name_policy
         , COUNT(DISTINCT d.event_id) AS sevents
         , SUM(d.item_qty) AS qty_show
      FROM data d
     WHERE d.event_status LIKE 'Show%'
     GROUP BY d.payor, d.name_policy, d.program
)
, ns AS
(
    SELECT d.name_policy
         , COUNT(DISTINCT d.event_id) AS nsevents
         , SUM(d.item_qty) AS qty_no_show
      FROM data d
     WHERE d.event_status LIKE 'No Show%'
     GROUP BY d.payor, d.name_policy, d.program
)
SELECT DISTINCT 
       d.payor
     , d.name_policy
     , d.program
     , sh.sevents
     , sh.qty_show
     , ns.nsevents
     , ns.qty_no_show
  FROM data d
  LEFT JOIN sh ON d.name_policy = sh.name_policy
  LEFT JOIN ns ON d.name_policy = ns.name_policy
;
```

Comment: thanks for your help @j spratt. your answers are helpful.